# I am searching extensible mail plugin for Hudson

Tags: hudson

I want to send reports about every Hudson job build ito mail. Mail address must be get by certain rule, for example: committer - vpupkin, his mail - vasya.pupkin@co.com. I have script which makes this transformation. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an LDAP directory. You should be able to resolve the email address for a user through an email property of the user in the LDAP. Don't know if that also works with Active Directory (but you should be able to access your AD with the LDAP protocol).

Answer (score 0):

The [Email-Ext Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin) is the most feature-rich facility for sending out email from Hudson.

For example, it can be configured to email the committer(s) who made changes since the last successful build.

Comment: i didn't find in email-ext possibilty to make transofrmation about i said

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Email-Ext Plugin, as mentioned is the most feature-rich email pluggin for Hudson.

You can enable an option to mail every commiter for success, failure and other...

I don't do any transformations on the e-mails though... I am configuring the profile of every user, where I update their e-mail address using their actual one.

Comment: At the first page of Hudson I get a link named People and another one for Build History... Top Right on the window... From the people menu I get to see all my users... If I login as a Hudsocn admin, then I can go to each and every one and configure their personal information, among them is their mail address

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/RegEx+Email+Plugin
made for this plugin shell script, which generates its config

Comment: Worst case scenario you have to configure one regex for every username though. (e.g. jdoe -> john.doe@example.com)

Comment: Depends on the amount of users you have. If you have 5 it doesn't make a big difference, but if you have 50 or more, it the configuration becomes cumbersome and might impact the performance of Hudson, to look up the email a address. I prefer lists or an LDAP look up (LDAP makes it easy to reuse the email for other applications too --> central point of configuration)